# iOS WebView Save Image Without Downloading It

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

After getting an URL from a JavaScript function that I need to evaluate on a UIWebView/WKWebView I download an image by using this Swift function to obtain the image and save it:

```
func saveImage(URL: NSURL) {
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: URL)
    img = UIImage(data: imageData)
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately I can't use this Swift function / obtain image data, when there is no internet connection. Now I ask myself whether it is possible to get image data by using JavaScript and then convert it to UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the js to give you the `base64` of that image and in **swift** layer:

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!
```

**objective c**:

```
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strBase64 options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```